# What is best Index for this MySQL statement to improve performance?

Tags: mysql, subquery, greatest-n-per-group, database-performance

I have a table containing the temperature values from x number of sensors which report temperature changes.  When a change API is received, the new temp is recorded and a cache is rebuilt for quick display to clients.  But I keep running into timing issues (throttling) with this query taking too long.

```
SELECT t.unit,t.temperature,t.dateAdded FROM Device_y_Data t 
WHERE t.deviceIndex=1 AND t.dateAdded=  
    (SELECT b.dateAdded FROM Device_y_Data b 
     WHERE b.deviceIndex=1  AND b.unit=t.unit 
     ORDER BY b.dateAdded DESC LIMIT 0,1) 
ORDER BY t.unit
LIMIT 0, 30

Table structure:
id  int(10)          
dateAdded   timestamp
deviceIndex tinyint(3)
unit    tinyint(3)
temperature decimal(4,1)

Indexes:
Keyname    Type Unique  Packed  ColumnComment
PRIMARY     BTREE   Yes No      id
dateAdded   BTREE   No  No      dateAdded   
deviceIndex BTREE   No  No      deviceIndex
                                unit
```

The result is a list of the most recent temps for each unit:

```
unit    temperature dateAdded   
1       67.0        2014-03-26 10:28:11
2       66.0        2014-03-26 10:26:01
3       68.0        2014-01-11 15:41:24
4       67.0        2014-01-15 09:53:16
5       67.0        2014-01-11 10:36:17
```

The EXPLAIN:

```
id  select_type         table   type    possible_keys   key         key_len ref     rows    Extra   
1   PRIMARY             t       ALL     deviceIndex     NULL        NULL    NULL    7035    Using where; Using filesort
2   DEPENDENT SUBQUERY  b       index   deviceIndex     dateAdded   4       NULL    1       Using where
```

In previous experiments I've tried MAX(), etc.  Other answers here on stackoverflow pointed me to the use of LIMIT and ORDER BY which did improve performance.  If I cannot figure out how to optimize this query, I guess I could programmatically query each unit's most recent temp.

The current database has 7000 rows.   Not much!  But the slowMySQL_logs show:
Query_time: 19.673578  Lock_time: 0.000239 Rows_sent: 5  Rows_examined: 5900033.   Seems like I could bring down the rows examined!

Thank you in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Fetch the row which has the Max value for a column](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/121387/fetch-the-row-which-has-the-max-value-for-a-column)

Comment: Looking at my question, I'm wondering my I need the id column.  I pretty sure unique deviceIndex,unit,datetime could be enforced.  Then would only need one index?

Comment: Thank you Mr Karwin - I read through the question you referred to and found your answer.  I've refactored the table and index and am trying the LEFT OUTER JOIN sql.   Seems to be working great... but I have to wait until hostmoster.com unthrottles me to test properly.  Thanks!